# Extract Data from <script> in html

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract data from an HTML script without success.
I'm able to get all the text content of the script that has the data I'm looking for, all I have to do is extract the relevant data.

```
response = requests.get('https://www.yad2.co.il/item/ajyw4gne', cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
more_data = soup.find_all("script")[13]
```

link : https://www.yad2.co.il/item/ajyw4gne

[image: The data in the website]
[image: The data from the script]

Comment: That's Javascript code.  You code hack your way with regular expressions, or you can switch to Selenium and let the Chrome browser interpret the Javascript for you.

Comment: @Tim Roberts I know I can do it with Selenium but I'm sure there is another way without selenium

Comment: Wishful thinking is not a good engineering strategy.  The numbers are not in the HTML you receive.  You have to execute the Javascript.  End of story.

Comment: @Tim Roberts look on the solution of Driftr95 this is what I looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>**Note:** I think selenium would definitely be the better approach for scraping this site. The function below is meant for sites with far more readable JavaScript (where the target information is conveniently packaged in JSON).</sup>

I have a function **[`findObj_inJS`](https://pastebin.com/UVcLniSG)** that uses [`slimit`](https://slimit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to parse JavaScript and extract variables and other values. The scripts on this page are not very readable, but if you use the function as below,

```py
jScript = soup.find(lambda s: s.name=='script' and 'window.__NUXT__' in s.text)
jScript = jScript.text if jScript else '0 SCRIPTS CONTAINING "window.__NUXT__"'
jsStr = jScript.replace('class:', 'was_class:').replace('default:', 'was_default:')
jsData = findObj_inJS(jsStr, [
    'info_text', 'info_title', 'search_text', 'date_of_entry',
    'info_bar_items', 'important_info_items', 'main_title', 'second_title'
], findAll=True, jStrict=False)
```

then `jsData` [as JSON] looks like

```json
{
  "info_text": [
    "בפרויקט יפו בשדרה  .\n\nדירת 4 חדרים מהמגזינים, יפיפייה ומוארת הפונה לגינה פנימית ושקטה.\n\n99 מ\"ר + 12 מ\"ר מרפסת, מטבח חדש ומאובזר, סוויטת הורים מפנקת חניה תת קרקעית ומחסן.\n\nלוקיישן מרהיב מרחק הליכה משוק הפשפשים, הנמל, יפו העתיקה ובקרבת תחנת הרכבת הקלה"
  ],
  "info_title": [
    "על הנכס"
  ],
  "search_text": [
    "דירה דירות למכירה חדרים ב תל אביב יפו , מכללת תל אביב יפו, דקר , חסידי האומות 22 $FurnitureInfo בפרויקט יפו בשדרה  .\n\nדירת 4 חדרים מהמגזינים, יפיפייה ומוארת הפונה לגינה פנימית ושקטה.\n\n99 מ\"ר + 12 מ\"ר מרפסת, מטבח חדש ומאובזר, סוויטת הורים מפנקת חניה תת קרקעית ומחסן.\n\nלוקיישן מרהיב מרחק הליכה משוק הפשפשים, הנמל, יפו העתיקה ובקרבת תחנת הרכבת הקלה. רון (לשלוח ווטסאפ אם לא זמין) דירה 4 $Floor_text $TotalFloor_text $Amudim_text $Furniture_text $PandorDoors_text מיזוג מעלית חניה $Grating_text גישה לנכים אזור תל אביב יפו $Immediate_text ממ\"ד מרפסת מחסן $sunpatio_text ₪ $Meshupatz_text $Porch_text $yehidatdiur_text במצב שמור הצג רחוב הצג מספר בית מזגן תדיראן עם מחיר, עם תמונה, חניה, הצג רק מושבים וקיבוצים, מעלית, מיזוג, מיזוג, ממ\"ד, מרפסת, מחסן, גישה לנכים, מזגן תדיראן, הצג רחוב, הצג מספר בית 4 חדרים | 111 מ״ר | 8 חסידי האומות 22 , מכללת תל אביב יפו, דקר"
  ],
  "date_of_entry": [
    "כניסה גמישה",
    "2022-12-28 00:00:00"
  ],
  "info_bar_items": [
    "[{\n  key: bs,\n  title: cF,\n  label: I,\n  titleWithoutLabel: a$\n},{\n  key: dE,\n  title: \"קומה 8\",\n  label: dD,\n  titleWithoutLabel: aF\n},{\n  key: \"meter\",\n  title: cG,\n  label: ip,\n  titleWithoutLabel: \"111\"\n},{\n  key: \"entrance\",\n  title: iq,\n  label: h,\n  titleWithoutLabel: iq\n}]"
  ],
  "important_info_items": [
    "[{\n  value: cz,\n  key: aR\n},{\n  key: \"רחוב\",\n  value: dC\n},{\n  value: \"8 מתוך 11 \",\n  key: dD\n},{\n  key: \"מ\\\"ר בנוי\",\n  value: \"99\"\n},{\n  value: \"לא צוין\",\n  key: \"מ\\\"ר גינה\"\n},{\n  link_url: \"http:\\u002F\\u002Fhomeprices.yad2.co.il\\u002Fneighborhood\\u002Fתל אביב יפו\\u002Fחסידי האומות-22\",\n  key: \"נתוני השכונה\",\n  value: \"לחץ כאן\"\n}]"
  ],
  "main_title": [
    "דירה למכירה בתל אביב יפו",
    "דירה&nbsp;למכירה&nbsp;בתל אביב יפו"
  ],
  "second_title": [
    "חסידי האומות 22 מכללת תל אביב יפו, דקר",
    "חסידי האומות&nbsp;22&nbsp;מכללת תל אביב יפו, דקר"
  ]
}
```

I can't read Hebrew, but I feel like at least some of the data you want is in there....

Comment: I need to scrape more than 10K pages so selenium will be way more slower... You did great job thanks !

Comment: @yoavlv12 glad to help! slimit can take a few sec to parse too, so you might want to take a look at the API as well? something like [`requests.get('https://www.yad2.co.il/api/item/ajyw4gne').json()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekekq.png) - the only issue is that sometimes it gets redirected to a captcha....

Comment: Thanks again ! I have already find a way to pass the captcha

Comment: @yoavlv12 may I ask how? I'm terrible at getting past any security and this could be useful in the future